# Proof that a matrix is invertible if and only if meets this property.

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_n(K)$ and I am told to prove that $A\in GL_n(K)$ if and only if meets
$A\Biggl(\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ ... \\ x_n \end{matrix}\Biggr)=\Biggl(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ ... \\ 0 \end{matrix}\Biggr)$ then $x_1,...,x_n = 0$

As a tip I am told to consider $\beta$ the base of a vector space $V$ with $n$ dimension and $f\in \operatorname{End}V)$ whose associated matrix is $A$.

I don't know how to use that "tip" to prove that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose that $A$ is invertible and $Ax=0$. Then $x=A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}(0)=0$ as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by your tip, consider  the endomorphism $f$ represented by this matrix in a given basis of a $K$-vector space $V$ with dimension $n$.

Remember that $A$ is invertible if and only if $f$ is an isomorphism (more exactly, an automorphism since $f$ is an endomorphism).

Now in a finite dimensional space, $f$ is an automorphism if and only if it is injective (and also if and only if it is surjective).

Now, how do you characterise an injective linear map?

*Some more details*:

$f$ is injective (hence bijective) if and only if $\ker f=\{0\}$, i.e. if and only if
$$(f(v)=0)\implies (v=0).$$
What is the relation between $f(v)$ and $A$?

Comment: A linear transformation is injective when $Ker f = {0_v}$. But I do not know how to get to the matrix form from there.

Comment: I've added some details. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions, but there is something that I don't get. To get the images of the linear transformation $f$, being $v$ any vector of $V$ and ${v_1,...,v_n}$ a base of V we do. $f(v) = (v_1 ... v_n)A\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\...\\\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$ being $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\...\\\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$ the coordinates of $v$ with the base ${v_1,...,v_n}$. I don't understand which is the relation between that and $Ax=0$.

Comment: Let's call $(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)$ the (unknown) coordinates of a vector $v$ in the kernel. Then $f(v)=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$. So $v\in\ker f$ means the coordinates of $v$ satisfy the linear system of equations defined by $A$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But what happens with the matrix with the base vectors $(v_1...v_n)$ that are also in the multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: A matrix operation is invertible if it is injective and surjective. If $Ax=0$ for some non-zero vector $x$, then $A$ is not injective, so it is not invertible. The contrapositive is that $A$ being invertible implies $Ax=0$ only for $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible, then using $Rank-nullity$ $theorem$, we can proove that $\text{Ker}(A) = {0}$, so if $A(x) = 0$ then $x=0$.

Reciprocally, if $A$ meets the condition:

$A\Biggl(\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ ... \\ x_n \end{matrix}\Biggr)=\Biggl(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ ... \\ 0 \end{matrix}\Biggr)$ then $x_1,...,x_n = 0$, it means that $\text{Ker}(A) = {0}$. Using again the $Rank-nullity$ $theorem$, we can prove that $\text{Rank}(A) = n$, which ensures us that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: We have learnt the rank-nullity theorem just for lineal applications and not for matrices. So I have to use the linear aplication whose associated matrix is A to prove that. I know that there is a link between them as matrices and linear applications are isomorphic but I do not know how to "pass" from matrices to linear applications and vice versa. Hope you understood my problem.